# Displaying text on multiple lines in Facebook News Feed Story

Tags: facebook

I am trying to make a Facebook application and I would like to publish stories on Users' News Feeds.  The problem i am having is that i would like to show text in multiple lines but HTML tags aren't allowed ([Allowed Tags](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Allowed_FBML_and_HTML_Tags#Feed.2FStream_Stories:_Allowed_Tags)). However, i recently received a news story from another application which had a list style story posted which is exactly what i am looking for (see image below) - so it looks like it can be done!

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to play with attachment property while publishing your stream to feed. You could put the data inside the 'properties' attribute which will be stroing your lines one after another. So to my mind it should look like:

```
var attachment = {
...some properties...
'properties': {
    'line1': 'text for line 1',
    'line2': 'text for line 2',
    'line3': 'text for line 3',
},
...some properties...
};
```

Comment: Thanks LapKom - I had tried this approach but it didn't work, however i must have had something wrong because I tried again after your suggestion and it works great! Thanks!